# complete table with required fields for any inventory management software

Tags: database-design

am trying to learn database application using c# and SQL . can anyone provide me the complete table with required fields for any inventory management software.

Comment: hello anyone can help me plssssss

Comment: i think i have registered one of the worst site

Comment: Inventory Management is a broad topic. 

You should start by reading some books, listed at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/ready-to-use-database-models-example/23831#23831